# ArgumentException in Tablets.Count method

Tags: c#, exception, tablet

sistematically, but only on one PC, while executing this code:

```
using Microsoft.Ink;
```

...

```
Tablets allTablets = new Tablets();
int numTablet = allTablets.Count;
```

I get this exception.

> System.ArgumentException: Valore non compreso nell'intervallo previsto. {In English --> Value not in the right range}
>    in Microsoft.Ink.InkTabletsClass.get_Count()
>    in Microsoft.Ink.Tablets.get_Count()

How could a COUNT throw this kind of exception?
Does it means that the Count method return a value that is not int?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this all the code you have?

Comment: I used ILSpy to inspect the code.  That property returns the value of a COM object with an internal implementation we can't access.  The COM interface is `Microsoft.Ink.IInkTablets`, and the COM method invoked has a dispatch ID of 2.  I have no idea what that means tho.

Comment: Ah ha, found it.  It invokes this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms821593.aspx

Comment: Also I tried to inspext that class with ILSpy, without success.

Answer (score 1):

> How could a COUNT throw this kind of exception?

Because of some logic that is implemented in the getter of the `Count` property of the `Tablets` class. It is in the getter that the exception is thrown.

> Does it means that the Count method return a value that is not int?

No. An `int` property can only return an `int` value or throw an exception. It can never return a value of any other type. The compiler enforces this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works for me. That being said, I have encountered similar exceptions so many times before that I now make it a habit to check for null objects first. So, I would use:

```
Tablets allTablets = new Tablets();
int numTablet = 0;
if (allTablets != null)
    numTablet = allTablets.Count;
```

To answer your question, for some reason `new Tablets()` returns null instead of an empty `ICollection`.

Comment: That would be a `NullReferenceException` rather than `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Good point @KlitosKyriacou. But handling the null Tablets should get around the issue nonetheless.

Comment: I do think that allTablets!=null doesn't avoid the error, but I will put it anyway.

Comment: Can I suppose that if allTablets.Count throws ArgumentException it means that there is no tablet devices attached to the pc and threat like it gives me back a Count=0?